# Table Positioning difference in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out the positioning problem using table in firefox and IE.
The fiddle will show the complete problem properly http://jsfiddle.net/qfDB9/ Even after providing proper height and width the problem persists. The actual reason I created the table is perfectly shown in Chrome whereas IE and Firefox has positioning problem.

**CSS:**

```
table tr #number_table {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
}
table tr #photo_table {
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
table tr #description_table {
    width:400px;
    padding-bottom:2em;
    font-size:20px;
}
table tr #band_name {
    text-align:center;
    height:25px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"  width="600px" style="color:#000;">
<tr>
    <td id="number_table">1</td>
    <td rowspan="2" id="photo_table"><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/The_Fabs.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/The_Fabs.JPG" width="140px" height="140px"/></a></td>
    <td rowspan="4" id="description_table">something something <br><br><br><br>something something <br><br><br><br>something something <br><br><br><br>something something <br><br><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td id="band_name">Something</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vertically align the content in the `<tr>` tags

`table tr { vertical-align:top; }`

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qfDB9/8/)**

*I might also add that you should consider using `div's` instead of `tables`*

Comment: Here is a quick demo of the same layout using only [divs](http://jsfiddle.net/qfDB9/11/)

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** Check This out. Just Add `valign="top"` to the `<tr>` or `<td>`

**DEMO HERE:** http://jsfiddle.net/qfDB9/9/

Comment: well the vertical-align is the property i learnt today. :) . Your fiddle helped me

Comment: @AbhishekFulzele Ohhh k than please accept my answer and click on "Tick Mark" and vote up too if u liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**, Always try too use the semantic code. like using thead, tbody, as it helps in implementing the CSS too. Also help in streamlining the CSS throughout the site.

**Solution** You can add this CSS "`table tbody td{vertical-align:top;}`" so all the content in all `<td>`s should be align to top. So if you have to give some table heading which are usually align bottom then you can handle by `<thead> <th>` "vertical-align:bottom.".

Please refer the code here:

**HTML**

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"  width="600px" style="color:#000;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="number_table">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2" id="photo_table"><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/The_Fabs.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/The_Fabs.JPG" width="140px" height="140px"/></a></td>
      <td rowspan="4" id="description_table">something something <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        something something <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        something something <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        something something <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="band_name">Something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table thead th{vertical-align:bottom;}
table tbody td{vertical-align:top;}


table tr #number_table {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;

}
table tr #photo_table {
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
table tr #description_table {
    width:400px;
    padding-bottom:2em;
    font-size:20px;
}
table tr #band_name {
    text-align:center;
    height:25px;
}
```

You can refer to the fiddle too:  **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/sU3SS/**

Let me know if the helps!

Enjoy!!

Comment: well the vertical-align is the property i learnt today. :) . Your fiddle helped me

Comment: Thanks! if you like it, then you must atleast vote uop the answers you thought help you... and tick the most helpful one.. Happy Coding!